# OpenOffice source code for power point pptx open and extraxt to images and export to swf

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-impress

I need to find the source code for openoffice powerpoint fuinctions for 
opening a pptx,
Reading slides,
editing,
find the slide transitions,
convert slides to bitmaps,
export to swf or other video formats.

How to find out the source code in openoffice?.

Comment: Hi Kaywin , which tool/framework you used, can you please share.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenOffice source code is available at http://www.openoffice.org/download/source/.

If you are asking about macros to control OpenOffice Impress, then there is a little information on the web, such as [Control Libreoffice Impress from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092424/control-libreoffice-impress-from-python/33132172#33132172).

However Impress is not as well documented as Writer, so use [XrayTool](http://berma.pagesperso-orange.fr/index2.html) on an Impress presentation component to find out what functionality is available.

Here is discussion about a macro that may work for exporting SWF: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=67088.